# Help with 1-Wire to I2C translate

Tags: i2c, 1-wire

Please, someone.

I want to use a temperature sensor (DS18B20) in an I2C only shield ([Tentacle Mini](https://www.whiteboxes.ch/tentacle/tentacle-mini-quickstart)), but this sensor is One Wire only. Can I write an I2C code to change the 1-Wire to I2C for this sensor? I think to use the ([DS2482-800](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/controllers-expanders/DS2482-800.html)) bridge, but I don't know how to do...

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you connect the one-wire device (and if needed pullup resistor) to some other pin at the header rather than through the shield?

Comment: I recently wrote a Cosa TWI device driver for the DS2482. The example sketch actually uses a DS18B20. For further details please see https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/tree/master/libraries/DS2482.

Comment: An alternative is to use the I2C SDA pin to both I2C and 1-Wire.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, the DS18B20 uses One-Wire interface. I2C is a Two-Wire interface. Pratically, you can't use the Arduino to translate that, BUT I found the  [DS28E17](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/controllers-expanders/DS28E17.html), a module that could translate the the 2 methods of communication. It should work but I havent tested it.

[image]

The DS28E17 is a 1-Wire slave to I2C master bridge device that interfaces directly to I2C slaves at standard (100kHz max) or fast (400kHz max). Data transfers serially by means of the 1-Wire® protocol, which requires only a single data lead and a ground return. Every DS28E17 is guaranteed to have a unique 64-bit ROM registration number that serves as a node address in the 1-Wire network. Multiple DS28E17 devices can coexist with other devices in the 1-Wire network and be accessed individually without affecting other devices. The DS28E17 allows using complex I2C devices such as display controllers, ADCs, DACs, I2C sensors, etc. in a 1-Wire environment. Each self-timed DS28E17 provides 1-Wire access for a single I2C interface.

Hope I helped you.